# Tricky, slow loop in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following Python code:

```
import json
import numpy as np

def generate(n, file, emax):
    data = {'n': n}
    adj = np.empty(n, dtype='object')

    for v in np.arange(n):
        erand = np.random.randint(1, emax + 1)
        adj[v] = {'v': int(v), 'e': np.random.choice(n, erand, replace=False).tolist()}

    # ndarrays are not JSON serializable
    data['adj'] = adj.tolist()

    with open(file, 'w') as graph:
        json.dump(data, graph, indent=2)
```

which is INCREDIBLY slow for n bigger than 10^4. I've tried a lot of stuff to make it faster, including np.apply_over_axis and what not, but I haven't been able to get a working version. The structures involved also make the code difficult to work with.

I feel like this is one of those problems where the solution will be instant -- but I lack the necessary experience in Python to get there.

If it's anything of help, I essentially want to generate random graphs, and would prefer to not use anything other than pure Python and NumPy.

Example output:

```
{
  "n": 10,
  "adj": [
    {
      "v": 0,
      "e": [
        0,
        7,
        5,
        6
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 1,
      "e": [
        5,
        4,
        6,
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 2,
      "e": [
        8,
        5,
        4,
        2,
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 3,
      "e": [
        4,
        8
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 4,
      "e": [
        8,
        4
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 5,
      "e": [
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 6,
      "e": [
        9,
        2
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 7,
      "e": [
        9
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 8,
      "e": [
        7
      ]
    },
    {
      "v": 9,
      "e": [
        4,
        2,
        9,
        6,
        3
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit: I had said in the original post that I wanted connected graphs. That was a mistake on my part -- I just wanted to guarantee that every vertex is connected to at least one other.

Comment: This would be much simpler if you were to represent the graph with an adjacency matrix. Then you could just sample an n x n binary matrix, where position (i, j) is 1 iff the two nodes i and j are connected. This matrix can be sampled in one step.

Comment: Kindly explain what your code is supposed to do, and one example of inputs and outputs expected

Comment: Collecting those `v` dictionaries in a list (e.g. `alist.append(v)`) is slightly faster than linking them to the object dtype array.  But the real time consumer is creating all those dictionaries.  There's no `numpy` short cut to doing that.  JSON is a string representation of nested lists and dictionaries, so there's not much of a way around that.

Comment: @xdurch0: I am dealing with sparse graphs, this is why I am avoiding using an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @alan.elkin: I'll edit in an expected output. The input is just the four parameters (mode does nothing for now though), the code generates random representations of graphs.

Comment: @Astly. Generate using a sparse matrix (scipy), and dump to json by scanning a triangle

Comment: @MadPhysicist: running scipy.sparse.random for n=m=10^5 returns the following funny error message:

"Unable to allocate 74.5 GiB for an array with shape (10000000000,) and data type int64".

Comment: I'd have to see the exact `sparse.random` expression (and traceback); but evidently you are trying to create too large of a matrix, even though it's sparse.  I'm not sure why `@MadPhysicist thinks a sparse matrix would help with the speed.

Comment: @hpaulj. Not speed as much as space

Comment: What aspect of that code guarantees that the graphs are connected? (Aside from the fact that most graphs with are connected, unless they are very sparse.)

Comment: also: what value of `emax` are you using in the tests which are very slow?

Comment: @rici: the graphs are always connected because a random number of edges between 1 and emax are generated.

Comment: @astly: That doesn't guarantee that the graph is connected. For example, a node could be connected only to itself.

Comment: @rici: true. See my proposed answer below!

Comment: @AstlyDichrar: but it's still possible that a group of nodes are only connected to each other. The denser the graph, the more likely it is that the graph is connected, but that's not a guarantee, particularly for sparse graphs.

Comment: @rici: that's true, but it was a mistake on my part to say that I wanted connected graphs. In fact, I just wanted to guarantee there were no vertices that aren't connected to any other vertex. Guaranteeing that what you said does not happen is a much more difficult problem, I think.

Comment: More complicated, indeed. By the way, do you want directed or undirected graphs? Your algorithm seems to be capable of producing both q->r and r->q, which is fine for a directed graph but redundant if the graph is undirected

Comment: Directed graphs, but this is one aspect I'm still thinking about what I want to do. That is, if my graph class should be capable of treating the same input as a directed or an undirected graph, or if the inputs should be different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the logic I used will produce the randomized graphs you are looking for, if I haven't incorporate all of the requirements, please let me know and I will remove this post. Please note, I did not include the code for file creation as the performance issue I think is related to the cost of using np.random functions.

Original Function:

```
def generate(n=100, file='', emax=10):
data = {'n': n}
adj = np.empty(n, dtype='object')

for v in np.arange(n):
    erand = np.random.randint(1, emax + 1)
    adj[v] = {'v': int(v), 'e': np.random.choice(n, erand, replace=False).tolist()}

# ndarrays are not JSON serializable
data['adj'] = adj.tolist()
return data
```

Faster Function:

```
def randGraph(n=100, file='', emax=10):
    data = {'n': n}
    nd = np.arange(n)
    masks = np.array(np.hstack((np.random.randint(0, 2, (n,emax)), np.zeros((n, n-emax)))), dtype=np.bool)
    for i in np.arange(n):
        np.random.shuffle(masks[i])
    data['adj'] = [{'v':i, 'e': nd[masks[i]].tolist()} for i in np.arange(n)] 
    return data
```

Faster functions with Numba's jit:

```
from numba import jit
@jit   
def randGraphJIT(n=100, file='', emax=10):
    data = {'n': n}
    nd = np.arange(n)
    masks = np.array(np.hstack((np.random.randint(0, 2, (n,emax)), np.zeros((n, n-emax)))), dtype=np.bool)
    for i in np.arange(n):
        np.random.shuffle(masks[i])
    data['adj'] = [{'v':i, 'e': nd[masks[i]].tolist()} for i in np.arange(n)] 
    return data
```

Results:

```
%timeit generate()
2.17 ms ± 76.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit randGraph()
663 µs ± 777 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit randGraphJIT()
284 µs ± 46.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For Nonsequential graphs:

```
def randGraphNonSeqential(n=100, file='', emax=10):
    data = {'n': n}
    nd = np.arange(n)
    nds = np.tile(nd, (n,1))
    masks = np.array(np.hstack((np.random.randint(0, 2, (n,emax)), np.zeros((n, n-emax)))), dtype=np.bool)
    for i in np.arange(n):
        np.random.shuffle(nds[i])        
        np.random.shuffle(masks[i])

    data['adj'] = [{'v':i, 'e': nds[i][masks[i]].tolist()} for i in np.arange(n)] 
    return data

@jit
def randGraphNonSeqentialJIT(n=100, file='', emax=10):
    data = {'n': n}
    nd = np.arange(n)
    nds = np.tile(nd, (n,1))
    masks = np.array(np.hstack((np.random.randint(0, 2, (n,emax)), np.zeros((n, n-emax)))), dtype=np.bool)
    for i in np.arange(n):
        np.random.shuffle(nds[i])        
        np.random.shuffle(masks[i])

    data['adj'] = [{'v':i, 'e': nds[i][masks[i]].tolist()} for i in np.arange(n)] 
    return data
```

Only marginal improvement without jit:

```
%timeit randGraphNonSeqential()
1.18 ms ± 6.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

still pretty good improvement with jit:

```
%timeit randGraphNonSeqentialJIT()
380 µs ± 363 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I managed pretty good performance with pure Python, I'll add my code in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, which was surprisingly much faster than using NumPy functions:

```
from json import dump
from random import randint, sample


def generate(n, path, density):
    '''Generates JSON files representing random directed graphs, where all vertices are connected to at least one other.

    Keyword arguments:
    n: number of vertices.
    path: path to JSON file.
    density: maximum number of edges of any vertex.'''
    data = {'n': n, 'm': 0}
    adj = [{'v': v} for v in range(n)]

    for v in range(n):
        adj[v]['e'] = sample(range(n), randint(1, density))
        while v in adj[v]['e']:
            adj[v]['e'] = sample(range(n), randint(1, density))
        data['m'] += len(adj[v]['e'])

    data['adj'] = adj

    with open(path, 'w') as graph:
        dump(data, graph, indent=2)
```

I want to write the while loop in a different way, but this seems to work well.

(edit: fix for edges of type (x, x))